Usage of がとられる this sentence?
————今の日本の絵の具に、純白は存在しない。
波や雲、雪の白さを表現するには、まだ絵の具が瑞々しい内に乾いた筆や布で拭き取り、
画用紙の素面を露出させる手法がとられる。
I'm not sure what to make of the last part of this explanation.
As far I can tell, the narrator explains that in today Japan painting tool there is no way to create pure white. Thus, in order to represent the clouds etc you wipe off the insides of the paint with a dry brush.
I believe "画用紙の素面を露出させる手法" is a method to expose the surface (素面 plain face/natural face?) of the drawing paper but what とられる。 here actually mean?

The verb used is 採る【とる】, which means "to adopt/choose/employ". 採られる is its simple passive form.

まだ絵の具が瑞々しい内に乾いた筆や布で拭き取り、画用紙の素面を露出させる手法がとられる。
A technique where the paint is wiped off with a dry brush or cloth while still fresh, exposing the raw surface of the drawing paper, is employed.

